# git ssh authentication issue (login-id vs user-name)

Tags: git, ssh

I configure Git server with SSH authentication. For some users git-shell is used.

I will describe the issue with an example:

1. Someone give me access for his git repo. I get an SSH account for git with username `jorooo`.
2. I am supposed to make commits and pushes with name `"Jorooo xxx" <jorooo@some-company.com>`
3. I start using git, but in some time, I decide to go bad! I change my git "user" and "email" (`git config --global user.name "Alexander Tomov"`)
4. I set my boss name and his email.
5. All my new commits seems to be from my boss name - git log command shows this.

For the server I set up, I want to eliminate this. Could I?

P.S. For SVN over HTTP, the HTTP username is used as ID, so this kind of issue is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to write a *receive hook* that checks uploaded commits (and rejects your push if they're not satisfactory), but this is not necessarily a good idea in a distributed workflow. After all, sometimes you legitimately want to push commits that were sent to you by someone else, e.g. as a patch via mail.

Git distinguishes two concepts here to make this a bit easier: the *author* and the *committer* of a commit. Suppose you write a hook that checks the committer for all uploaded commits – this is less likely to cause trouble even with a distributed workflow, but you'll still run into trouble if you fetch from one remote repository and push the retrieved commits to another. If that's not going to happen in your environment, you can *probably* make that kind of hook work.

In general, only give push access to your repositories to people you trust. Fake names are rather tame compared to, for example, deliberately introducing subtle bugs that can be written off as honest mistakes but cause lots of damage.